# Filing jointly, can I pay estimated taxes on behalf of my wife's side work?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, estimated-taxes, form-1099-misc

Quick background: I have an EFTPS account where I've paid estimated taxes in the past for some side work in programming. I haven't used it in years. My wife recently started a free lance writing gig and has earned some 1099-misc income. I've tried to set up an EFTPS account for her but that system is maddening and it mailed me something saying something about her information doesn't match (it didn't tell me what).

Because we file taxes jointly, can I pay estimated taxes on behalf of her income through my EFTPS account?

Comment: Are there self-employment tax implications for your wife's side-gig [ie: does she have another job maxing out SS contributions, which my limited understanding indicates is important]? Or are you strictly anticipating income taxes to be owed?

Comment: EFTPS is no longer the only way to pay electronically. IRS now has https://www.irs.gov/payments/direct-pay also.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks! Wish I'd known about this site before wasting a bunch of time with EFTPS. That site is horrendous.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon she doesn't have another job. Next step is trying to decipher how much to pay which seems to be a total mystery.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you guys will file jointly, you guys will have a single tax liability, and any taxes paid by either of you (whether it be by tax withholding or paying estimated taxes) counts toward that tax liability.